# Not able to run the PJSIP-JNI Wrapper on a standalone java application

Tags: java, sip, pjsip, jain-sip, jniwrapper

I need some documentation for using PJSIP as a Standalone Java Application to understand the flow and implement the Java Wrapper. I have downloaded PJSIP-JNI wrapper, but i am not able to understand how to run the application. I am really struck from many days. please some one help me in using the PJSIP-JNI as a standalone Java application, say, i want to test the connection to my SIP server through my main class. If some one can suggest some other libraries then it will really great.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use JAIN SIP http://code.google.com/p/jain-sip/ for an Open Source Java SIP Stack instead of PJSIP and going with JNI ?
You could even go higher level with SIP Servlets https://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/ to avoid taking care of low level coding and focus on your business and routing logic or even higher level with RestComm https://code.google.com/p/restcomm/